# freeze_graph.py throws an error during build

Tags: python, c++, gcc, tensorflow

I'm trying to build freeze_graph.py as specified on the readme part:

> bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph && \
>   bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph \
>   --input_graph=some_graph_def.pb \
>   --input_checkpoint=model.ckpt-8361242 \
>   --output_graph=/tmp/frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=softmax
>
> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

But after the first command, it throws this error:

> ERROR:
>   /home/bernardo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bernardo/6ec3db0a5b478824b301f4851c10d381/external/boringssl/BUILD:91:1:
>   C++ compilation of rule '@boringssl//:crypto' failed: gcc failed:
>   error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
>   '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wl,-z,-relro,-z,now
>   -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-canonical-system-headers ... (remaining 42 argument(s) skipped):
>   com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process
>   exited with status 1. In file included from
>   /usr/include/stdint.h:25:0,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.1/include/stdint.h:9,
>                    from external/boringssl/src/include/openssl/base.h:60,
>                    from external/boringssl/src/include/openssl/chacha.h:18,
>                    from external/boringssl/src/crypto/chacha/chacha.c:17:
>   /usr/include/features.h:331:4: error: #warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE
>   requires compiling with optimization (-O) [-Werror=cpp]  #  warning
>   _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
>       ^~~~~~~ cc1: all warnings being treated as errors Target //tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph failed to build Use
>   --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps. INFO: Elapsed time: 0.485s, Critical Path: 0.24s [bernardo@foobar-pc
>   tensorflow]$

I'm trying to run it to create a new .pb file to import in an Android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding `--copt=-O` to the build command.

The whole command used to build freeze_graph was:

```
bazel build --copt=-O --config=cuda  tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error it's saying it wants you to bazel build with "-O" option to get the optimized build.

Comment: bazel build -O tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph
----
Unrecognized option: -O

Comment: For bazel for C++ code, according to https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html you should use "-c opt".  (See --compilation_mode section)